# for loop returning empty list when calling a variable that is created inside loop

Tags: python, selenium

My code is:

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=iphone")

tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)

for product_tree in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@data-cel-widget, "search_result_")]'):

    title = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal"]/text()')

    price = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-price-whole"]/text()')

    itens_list = []

    itens_iph = {
        'title': title,
        'price': price,
    }

    itens_list.append(itens_iph)

print(itens_list)
```

When im trying to print itens_list, its returning []. I cant find a answer to this problem, and im stuck, could someone please help me? thanks!

Comment: You recreate the list every iteration of the loop. You should be creating the list _outside_ the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a variable inside of a block like a loop or an if statement will mean the variable's scope is that block of code. You need the scope of the variable to be outside of the loop and available to the whole file to do things with it both in and outside of the loop. It also has to be declared before you can append anything so it must be created outside of and before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an empty dictionary inside loop. So after each iteration the **itens_list** will be empty.

Move **iten_list** above for loop, It will work.

Here is the correction

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=iphone")

tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
itens_list = []
for product_tree in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@data-cel-widget, "search_result_")]'):

    title = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal"]/text()')

    price = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-price-whole"]/text()')


    itens_iph = {
        'title': title,
        'price': price,
    }

    itens_list.append(itens_iph)

print(itens_list)
```